# replace all strings to a default number in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame of numbers (int and floats) which results in a datatype of float for all columns.  or so I thought.

These tables are the result of OCR scanning to EXCEL.  in some case there's ascii or word values because of a bad scan.

How do I perform a blanket str value to default -999999 for all columns, all values in the DataFrame?

The problem I have is the pd.replace() function appears to be string specific.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try

```
 df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).fillna(-999999)
```

The pd.to_numberic function will convert all non-parsable strings to 'NaN' and the fillna replaces those values with the given value '-999999'

Comment: You can pass keyword args through `apply`.  So this should work: `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(-999999)`

Comment: @arcee123, did you try the answer?

Comment: Yes.  This appears to work exceptionally.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @arcee123, glad to know that it works as expected. Thank you  for the confirmation.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do regex match in pandas replace method py passing, **regex=True**

```
df.replace("^\w.*$", "-999999", regex=True)
```

From pandas replace function [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

> to_replace : str, regex, list, dict, Series, numeric, or None
>
> str or regex:
>
> - str: string exactly matching to_replace will be replaced with value
> - regex: regexs matching to_replace will be replaced with value
>
> list of str, regex, or numeric:
>
> - First, if to_replace and value are both lists, they must be the same length.
> - Second, if ***regex=True*** then all of the strings in both lists will be interpreted as regexs otherwise they will match directly. This doesn’t matter much for value since there are only a few possible substitution regexes you can use.
> - str and regex rules apply as above.

Comment: This will not work if there is a numeric value that comes as string. For example, '1' or ''10.05'

Comment: have you given it a try, for me it works for any string be it alphanumeric> "abcd123", integer > "10", negative integer > "-999", float > "10.03"